# Joda time zone different than JDK's

Tags: java, jodatime

In my client, I have this code:

```
System.out.println("Java tz: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
System.out.println("Joda tz: " + ISOChronology.getInstance());
```

These two lines run one after another. I never set time zone or `user.timezone` manually, just rely on defaults read from the OS & local system.

When executed, they produce:

```
Java tz: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
Joda tz: ISOChronology[America/Phoenix]
```

System time zone is indeed Phoenix, not UTC. How can Joda be correct and JDK be wrong?

**EDIT**: This is a Windows 7 x64 host, JRE is 1.6.22 x64.

**EDIT 2**: Don't try to reproduce it. It only fails on some, not all systems (like a few dozen in our 3k user base). I already know Joda checks `user.timezone` and then `TimeZone.getDefault()`. So I am looking for an explanation on how can it be different between me calling `TimeZone` directly and Joda doing it by itself.

Comment: I have tested it on my Windows machine with JDK 1.6.0_22 and it shows my time zone, not UTC. Maybe you should add more info: OS, JDK version, maybe some environment variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say "defaults read from the OS & local system", there isn't a single, well-defined place to read this default from.  Even the API documentation itself says

> Gets the default `TimeZone` for this host. The source of the default `TimeZone` may vary with implementation.

So the simple answer is that Joda and your JVM are inferring the default time zone from different sources of information.  The point to remember about this is that **the default is a guess**, not something that the JVM can definitively get access to.

For Sun's 1.5.0_06 JVM on Linux, the following order is used:

1. Looks to environment variable TZ
2. Looks for the file /etc/sysconfig/clock and tries to find the "ZONE" entry.
3. Compares contents fo /etc/localtime with the contents of every file in /usr/share/zoneinfo recursively. When the contents matches, it returns the path and filename, referenced from /usr/share/zoneinfo.

Joda 1.6.2 uses:

1. The system property `user.timezone`.
2. If the above is `null` or not a valid identifier, the value of the JDK's `TimeZone` default is used.
3. If that fails, `UTC` is used.

So *if* you have the above versions of JDK and Joda, I suggest that the `user.timezone` property may be set in your environment.  Other versions may will use other algorithms to acquire the default, though.

Edit: In Sun's JDK 1.6.0_22, the default search first inspects the `user.timezone` property as well, and if that isn't found it looks up the `user.country` property in order to get the default value for a country.  If neither is set, the default of `GMT` is used.  So the results you observe may well change with your JVM version.

---

Edit 2: If you've got the source to both (and indeed the sources are both available), then you can simply trace it!  Step through the Joda call, to see if it does indeed defer to `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()`, and see what the returned value is.  Then invoke the JDK method directly and see what you get.

Looking at the JDK sources, it seems that the default timezone is accessed via an inheritable thread local.  Thus if someone somewhere calls `TimeZone.setDefault()`, it may or may not be visible in other threads, depending on whether they've looked up the version already.  If you're getting apparently anomalous results from debugging the calls, it could well be simply due to the fact that *different threads can have different default TimeZones*.

Comment: Thank you, but it still does not answer my question. I already know that both JDK and Joda use the same mechanism (`user.timezone`, then `TimeZone.getDefault()`). That's why I'm asking: how is it possible that one is different from the other?

Comment: @Konrad - updated, try checking the behaviour in a debugger and seeing if this could be a ThreadLocal issue.

Comment: I want to add that I prefer to start my Java programs from .bat or shell script with command line including `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Warsaw` (of course change it to your timezone).

Comment: Thanks for the verbose answer, but in the end it seems the reason is more likely this: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/tz_update.html. @Michał: That's what I'm going to use, but it requires much more work as I have users in more time zones. Thank you guys.