# How to convert from java.util.date to JodaTime and get same date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I follow this question: [Convert from java.util.date to JodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042587/convert-from-java-util-date-to-jodatime)

I have date: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1854
now I want to convert it to joda datetime:

> DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);

and now when I print this date I got:
1853-12-31T23:57:44.000+00:57:44

what is wrong and why my date changed ? How I can get the same date ?

UPDATE:

I get date using calendar:

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(1854, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
cal1.getTime()
```

UPDATE2:

propably there is problem with milseconds:

```
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(1854, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(1854, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(start.getMillis());
    System.out.println(cal1.getTime().getTime());
```

because this code return:

```
-3660598664000
-3660598799438
```

but I dont know why

UPDATE3:

[image]

Comment: what means +00:57:44? it's offset?

Comment: sorry my mistake I correct right date

Comment: whats the actual code you use to construct original Date object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok I solve it. Is isnt nice but it works what is important

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(datum);

    DateTime current = new DateTime(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

Joda-Time uses the accurate time-zone database, which has [Local Mean Time (LMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) for years before time-zones started. To quote Wikipedia:

> Local mean time is a form of solar time that corrects the variations of local apparent time, forming a uniform time scale at a specific longitude.

The JDK doesn't use LMT, thus the times differ.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have the date as type of java.util.date you can use

```
java.util.Date date = ....
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

this code

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(1854, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime start = new DateTime(cal1.getTime());
    System.out.println(start);
    System.out.println(cal1.getTime());
```

outputs :

```
1854-01-01T00:00:00.941Z
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1854
```

I imagine the millisecond discrepancy is calendar choosign the saem time of day as now, to start the milliseconds count on. Whereas joda-time chooses midnight. Or something similarly obtuse. I try and stay away from java's built in Calendar and Date, they are an abomination.

Comment: ok this can be right but you didint answer my question. how to convert date to joda time. Now you just create one datetime and one date

Comment: sorry but when I process this code my output is: 1853-12-31T23:57:44.866+00:57:44
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CET 1854

Comment: sorry but it isn't. You must be setting timezone or have different code.

Comment: you can see picture in question I dont lie

Comment: I am in prague so: UTC/GMT +2 hours

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4374809/106261 calendar and jodatime might be getting th etimezone from different places ...

Comment: hm but still there is different just 2 minutes and 16 s not hours

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by JodaStephen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405303/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

The Joda-Time team have instructed us to migrate to the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. So I was curious to try this problem in java.time and compare results.

The Question says the input data is for `CET` offset-from-UTC, but the code in the Question ignores that fact. My code below uses an offset of one hour ahead of UTC to account for `CET`.

### java.time

The [`CET`](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet) means one hour ahead of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Since we have only an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) and not a [full time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), I use the [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class, for `+01:00`.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of ( 1854 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ); // The nineteenth century.
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of ( "+01:00" );  // “CET” means one hour ahead of UTC.
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of ( localDateTime , offset );
Instant instant = odt.toInstant ();  // A moment on the timeline in UTC, with resolution in nanoseconds.
long m = instant.toEpochMilli ();

System.out.println ( "odt: " + odt + " | millis: " + m );
```

> odt: 1854-01-01T00:00+01:00 | millis: -3660598800000

### Joda-Time

Same code, but using Joda-Time 2.9.3.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHoursMinutes ( 1 , 0 );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime ( 1854 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , zone );
long millis = dateTime.getMillis ();

System.out.println ( "dateTime: " + dateTime + " | millis: " + millis );
```

> dateTime: 1854-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00 | millis: -3660598800000

Result is same as java.time.

### java.util.Calendar

For comparison only. Normally you should avoid the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes as they have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance ();
calendar.set ( 1854 , 0 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 );
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone ( "GMT+01:00" );
calendar.setTimeZone ( zone );
long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis ();

System.out.println ( "calendar: " + calendar + " | millis: " + millis );
```

> calendar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-3660598799715,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+01:00",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=1854,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=285,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0] | millis: -3660598799715

Different results. Here we have `-3660598799715` versus `-3660598800000` in java.time & Joda-Time, a difference of `285`.

## `Europe/Brussels`

I also tried all three with a time zone of `Europe/Brussels` rather than an offset-from-UTC.

In java.time. Using `ZonedDateTime` class rather than `OffsetDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of ( 1854 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ); // The nineteenth century.
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Brussels" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of ( localDateTime , zoneId );
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant ();  // A moment on the timeline in UTC, with resolution in nanoseconds.
long m = instant.toEpochMilli ();

System.out.println ( "zdt: " + zdt + " | millis: " + m );
```

> zdt: 1854-01-01T00:00+00:17:30[Europe/Brussels] | millis: -3660596250000

In Joda-Time. Only first line is different.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID ( "Europe/Brussels" );
```

> dateTime: 1854-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:17:30 | millis: -3660596250000

In java.util.Calendar. Some code except for the `TimeZone` line:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone ( "Europe/Brussels" );
```

> calendar: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-3660598799151,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Brussels",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Brussels,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=1854,MONTH=0,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=1,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=849,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0] | millis: -3660598799151

All three using `Europe/Brussels` differ from their version with offset of `+01:00`.

And again java.time & Joda-Time agree with each other (`-3660596250000`), while differing from `Calendar` (`-3660598799151`), a difference of `2,549,151` (about 42 and a half minutes).