# Inconsistency in handling date and time in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, calendar

I have noticed strange behavior of date and time in java. I have the following code:

```
public class TestDateTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Helsinki"));

        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

        assert(calendar.getTimeZone().equals(TimeZone.getDefault()));
        //Set 1899-12-30T23:00:00
        calendar.set(1899,11,30,23,0,0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

        long timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        java.util.Date calendarDateTime = new java.util.Date(timeInMillis);

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ofEpochMilli(timeInMillis), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println("Time in millis: " + timeInMillis);
        System.out.println("Date: " + calendarDateTime.toString());
        System.out.println("Local DateTime: " + localDateTime.toString());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Time in millis: -2209086000000
Date: Sat Dec 30 23:00:00 EET 1899
Local DateTime: 1899-12-30T22:39:49
```

timeInMillis must contain the number of milliseconds passed from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.
The instance of Date class stores number of milliseconds passed from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.
`Date.toString()` method returns local date and time for the default timezone.

So the `Date.toString()` and `LocalDateTime.toString()` must return the same date and time, but we see the difference (more than 20 minutes).

Is this a bug of java, or I use date and time incorrectly in Java?

Comment: LocalDateTime from what package?

Comment: It is standard Java 8 class from java.time package

Comment: What is your _actual_ timezone locale setting, as in `Europe/...?`

Comment: Europe/Helsinki I set it here TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Helsinki"));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a weirdness caused by Finland time change, see [Clock Changes in Helsinki, Finland (Helsingfors) in 1921](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/finland/helsinki?year=1921):

> May 1, 1921 - Time Zone Change (HMT → EET)
>
> When local standard time was about to reach
> Sunday, May 1, 1921, 12:00:00 midnight clocks were turned forward **0:20:11 hours** to
> Sunday, May 1, 1921, 12:20:11 am local standard time instead

Those 20 minutes 11 seconds seem to be what you're observing.

As [Jim Garrison said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42865778/5221149), `LocalDateTime` is correctly handling that, while `Calendar` is not.

In reality, it seems that the old `TimeZone` is getting the offset wrong, while the new `ZoneId` is getting it right, as can be seen in the following test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    compare(1800, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0);
    compare(1899,12,31, 23,59,59);
    compare(1900, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0);
    compare(1900,12,30, 23, 0, 0);
    compare(1921, 4,30,  0, 0, 0);
    compare(1921, 5, 1,  0, 0, 0);
    compare(1921, 5, 2,  0, 0, 0);
}
private static void compare(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.clear();
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Helsinki"));
    calendar.set(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, second);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0, ZoneId.of("Europe/Helsinki"));
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z XXX");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Helsinki"));
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z XXX");
    
    System.out.printf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d   %s = %d   %s = %d   %d%n",
                      year, month, day, hour, minute, second,
                      sdf.format(date), date.getTime(),
                      dtf.format(zdt), zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
                      date.getTime() - zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
}
```

*Output*

```
1800-01-01 00:00:00   1800-01-01 00:00:00 EET +02:00 = -5364669600000   1800-01-01 00:00:00 EET +01:39 = -5364668389000   -1211000
1899-12-31 23:59:59   1899-12-31 23:59:59 EET +02:00 = -2208996001000   1899-12-31 23:59:59 EET +01:39 = -2208994790000   -1211000
1900-01-01 00:00:00   1900-01-01 00:00:00 EET +02:00 = -2208996000000   1900-01-01 00:00:00 EET +01:39 = -2208994789000   -1211000
1900-12-30 23:00:00   1900-12-30 23:00:00 EET +01:39 = -2177548789000   1900-12-30 23:00:00 EET +01:39 = -2177548789000   0
1921-04-30 00:00:00   1921-04-30 00:00:00 EET +01:39 = -1536025189000   1921-04-30 00:00:00 EET +01:39 = -1536025189000   0
1921-05-01 00:00:00   1921-05-01 00:20:11 EET +02:00 = -1535938789000   1921-05-01 00:20:11 EET +02:00 = -1535938789000   0
1921-05-02 00:00:00   1921-05-02 00:00:00 EET +02:00 = -1535853600000   1921-05-02 00:00:00 EET +02:00 = -1535853600000   0
```

Comment: But Calendar class is used by oracle jdbc driver to handle DATE type. So we cannot guarantee the correct conversion from java.sql.Date to java.time.LocalDateTime?

Comment: If you extract the date from the `ResultSet` using [`getDate(String, Calendar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar)), passing in a calendar with UTC TZ, it should?

Answer (score 5):

`LocalDateTime` is CORRECT.  According to the TZ database, the GMT offset at that date was `1:39:49`:

```
# Zone  NAME        GMTOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Europe/Helsinki 1:39:49 -   LMT 1878 May 31
            1:39:49 -   HMT 1921 May    # Helsinki Mean Time
            2:00    Finland EE%sT   1983
            2:00    EU  EE%sT
```

Historical timezones are incredibly complex, and prior to standardization offsets were inherited from settings based on things like mean solar noon.  When going back that far just about any offset is possible, and the [IANA TZ database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) is the master reference for historical data.

From what I can see in the database, the weird offset did not get standardized to `2:00:00` until 1921 when HMT was replaced with EE(S)T.

Comment: So does Calendar or Date.toString() contain incorrect behavior?

Comment: No, `Date` is intended to hold UTC times only, and has long been recognized as an underpowered, obsolete interface that doesn't cope with time in a rational manner.  This is the reason for the existence of libraries like JodaTime, and the addition of the `java.time` package.

Comment: The Oracle guys and also S. Colebourne (the primary author of `java.time`-API) have suggested to remove the LMT-information entirely, see my answer. So I conclude that we cannot say. The new API is correct while the old API is wrong. They just behave different (inconsistency).

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, the difference is because the LMT ([local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time)) value is not being taken into account by the `Date` object. This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405303/634824), with regard to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) - the precursor to Java 8's [time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Additionally, [the Joda-Time FAQ](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/faq.html#wrongoffset) says the following:

> ### Why is the offset for a time-zone different to the JDK?
>
> There are two main reasons for this.
>
> The first reason is that both the JDK and Joda-Time have time-zone
> data files. It is important to keep both up to date and in sync if you
> want to compare the offset between the two.
>
> The second reason affects date-times before the modern time-zone
> system was introduced. The time-zone data is obtained from the
> time-zone database. The database contains information on "Local Mean
> Time" (LMT) which is the local time that would have been observed at
> the location following the Sun's movements.
>
> Joda-Time uses the LMT information for all times prior to the first
> time-zone offset being chosen in a location. **By contrast, the JDK
> ignores the LMT information. As such, the time-zone offset returned by
> the JDK and Joda-Time are different for date-times before the modern
> time-zone system.**

The last part (which I bolded) is relavent to both Joda-Time and Java 8, even though Java 8 has one set of time zone data files (unlike Joda-Time).

Comment: About the statement given in Joda-time ("the JDK ignores the LMT information"), this is not quite correct, see also my answer citating Xueming Shen from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

**To be more precise about API-inconsistency:**

While the new `java.time`-API always uses the LMT-informations of TZDB, we have also to state that the old JDK-class `java.util.TimeZone` makes a cut in year 1900 with the consequence that LMT-informations are not taken into account before the year 1900, but after 1900, yes, it is still taken into account! Just make your experiments with an appropriate zone... (Asia/Kamchatka for example)

We cannot really say that either the LMT-strategy of `java.time`-API is correct or the traditional 1900-strategy. Keep also in mind that there is an [open JDK-issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024267) to abolish the LMT-strategy. Citation:

> The current TimeZone code does not use LMT. Joda-Time does, as does
>   JSR-310. This is wrong.
>
> Recent discussion on the tzdb mailing list has indicated that the data
>   is not properly maintained or reliably linked to the city of the zone
>   ID. It is also relatively meaningless, being a notional value for a
>   single city within a large region.
>
> Removing LMT is a good thing.

And Xueming Shen from Oracle says as comment in this issue:

> The current j.u.TimeZone implementation DOES use LMT. If the LMT is
>   defined/used cross the 1900.1.1 j.u.TimeZone cutoff date (by the tzdb
>   data). For example the offset for Asia/Kamchatka from 1900.1.1 to the
>   1922.11.10 will be the LMT 10.34.36. Yes, if the LMT end date is before 1900.1.1, the LMT will not be used by the j.u.TZ.

As additional historical note, the JDK-issue was originally suggested by the main author of `java.time`-API S. Colebourne, see also the [ancestor](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/issues/332) on threeten-issue-tracker.