# Joda DateTimeZone.getName(long instant) returns invalid name

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In my machine, set timezone is (UTC) Coordinated Universal Time. But the below sample code returns Pakistan time and +5:00

```
private void Foo() 
{

 DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ZZ");
 DateTime dt = DateTime.now();

 System.out.println(dtf.print(dt));  // Prints +05:00, though expected is +00:00

 DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();

 System.out.println(" Get Name " + tz.getName(System.currentTimeMillis())); 
 // Prints Get Name Pakistan Time , although expected is Coordinated Universal Time

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine may be set to UTC, but it's possible that the JVM is set to something else.

From the [Joda Time docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) on `DateTimeZone.getDefault()`:

> The default time zone is derived from the system property user.timezone. If that is null or is not a valid identifier, then the value of the JDK TimeZone default is converted. If that fails, UTC is used.

So, you can pass the time zone to the JVM on startup:

```
java -Duser.timezone="UTC"
```

Or you can set the system time zone in the `TZ` environment variable, etc.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374809/634824) for more details.