# java Webstart application sporadically gets a wrong time zone (UTC)

Tags: java, swing, timezone, java-web-start

I develop a Swing WebStart application and got a problem with the date presentation due to wrong time zone. Here is my code:

```
LOG.info("TZ: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID() + " // " + System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
```

Output for about 70% of users is correct:

```
Europe/Berlin // Europe/Berlin
```

But output for about 30% of users is:

```
UTC // Europe/Berlin
```

Today I've got reproduced the "wrong date problem" but only for one Webstart Client. The second client, which was started 10 minutes after the first one, presents dates correctly (the first was still running). I've started application some times from Eclipse but date presentation was always correct.

I've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374733/joda-time-zone-different-than-jdks) post but still not understand why I can reproduce it only with a Webstart client and only sporadically.

OS: Windows 7. Java version: 1.8_31 x86

I've searched for `TimeZone.setDefault()` in code but nothing found.